# Setting default value of foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have three tables in database:

```
user (user_id(pk), username, email, password, country_code(fk), city_id(fk));

country (country_code(pk), country name);

city (city_id(pk), city_name);
```

Country and city tables are already filled with details. user table is blank. All table has default value 'none' for each record.

And I have a simple interface which asks for email and password for registration.

So, when user enters the email and password, the mysql does not allow to insert. It shows following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This is because `user` table can not insert any values for `country_code` and `city_id` that are not in `country` and `city` table. And user has not yet given the value, the default value is none, which is not in both parent tables.

So, How to deal with integrity? Should I give `NULL` as the default value of both foreign keys in child table(which is `user`)? I tried giving default values NULL and it is working. I want to know that if it won't make any trouble for integrity issues in my database design? Is it a proper way?

Comment: Yes, `null` should be default. No value. But you need to allow null values for those columns

Comment: @juergend thanks..and Should i allow null values in only those columns which have foreign keys?

Comment: In all columns that can have no value. Why store something if you don't need to?

Answer (score 0):

With these design you could simply add a '*(none)*' record for tables `country` and `city`.

This way you'd have two "*magic values*", `country_code` and `city_id` related to this '*(none)*' records, to be used as default values of *country_code(fk)*, *city_id(fk)* in new entries of user table.

You could also avoid "*magics*" (i mean constant values of a special meaning) for `country_code` and `city_id` only hard-wiring '*(none)*' value for both `country_name` and `city_name` and selecting the corresponding primary keys by mean of a where criteria on `country_name` and `city_name`.